# python error handling while passing a function's response as parameter to another function

Tags: python, function, exception

I am new to python and need to understand how python works with exception in the following case:

```
func1(func2(param1, param2), expected_value)
```

where

```
func1(param_x, expected):
```

returns true if param_x is as expected. Here param_x might be an exception raised by func2. I might be expecting the exception and need to assert the same.

My question is:

If `func2` raises an exception, how does it behave?

Comment: It will simply break the execution of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If param_x is an exception that is *returned* by func2, then you can simply check the value of param_x inside func1 (e.g., param_x == NameError). If param_x is an exception that is *raised* by func2, then the program will die an print a traceback describing where in func2 the error occurred. If you'd like to handle the error in the latter case, I would suggest setting the return value of func2 outside of the func1 call and wrapping it in a try, except block. e.g.,

```
try:
    param_x = func2(param1, param2)
except NameError:
    param_x = new_val
func1(param_x, expected_value)
```

If you wanted to pass the raised error as a parameter to func1, you could try something like:

```
try:
    param_x = func2(param1, param2)
except NameError:
    param_x = NameError
except AnotherError:
    param_x = AnotherError
except:
    print "UNEXPECTED ERROR"
    raise
func1(param_x, expected_value)
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that in your code `func1(func2(param1, param2), expected_value)`, if `func2` raises an exception, `func1` will never be called.

That's because an exception breaks out of the ordinary evaluation of Python statements. When an exception is raised, the statement where it happens stops being evaluated immediately. Unless that statement is within a `try` block, the function that was being run also stops immediately and the exception bubbles up to the places where the function was called.

If you want `func1` to catch an exception called by `func2`, you need to have `func1` do the calling of `func2` itself. That is, the arguments to `func1` can't just be `func2`'s return value, but must include the function and its arguments in some form. This is how the [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) method of `unittest.TestCase` works, in its simplest form. You pass a callable and a set of arguments, along with the exception type you expect to be raised. Another option might be to pass a zero-argument callable that has `func2`'s arguments already bound, such as a `functools.partial` instance or a lambda expression like `lambda: func2(param1, param2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Depends how you want it to handle the exception. Look into try-except blocks.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

If unhanded it breaks the script.